# Network monitoring windows vista

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy-to-use tool to monitor incoming network traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/68115/easy-to-use-tool-to-monitor-incoming-network-traffic)

I need an application(freeware) for Windows Vista which shows me the current network
usage by individual applications. Can you suggest one?

Comment: This has been addressed in several other questions. One such example would be http://superuser.com/questions/96552/network-monitoring-windows-vista

Answer (score 0):

[NetLimiter Monitor](http://www.netlimiter.com/) is up to the task:

[image]

NetLimiter Monitor is freeware.

Answer (score 0):

**[AnVir Task Manager Free](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/AnVir-Task-Manager-Free.shtml)** features realtime network monitoring for each process:

[image]