# Network Monitor Tool

Tags: windows, networking, software-rec, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy-to-use tool to monitor incoming network traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/68115/easy-to-use-tool-to-monitor-incoming-network-traffic)

I want a tool similar to task manager that can show per-process network bandwidth. Best is if it combines the functionality of task manager. I tried Anvir Task Manager, but this feature doesn't work properly in it.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/68115/easy-to-use-tool-to-monitor-incoming-network-traffic. There are quite a lot others which you can find. Good luck!

Comment: non of them fits. i want per process bandwidth utilization

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 7, the built-in Resource Monitor can do this. Check out the Network tab:

[image]

There is also [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) (the Monitor version is free), although it doesn't really have the Task Manager functionality:

[image]