# local network traffic

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

Which is the best program for monitoring local network traffic

Comment: Are there any restrictions what OS the "sniffer" should use?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use http://superuser.com/questions/68115/easy-to-use-tool-to-monitor-incoming-network-traffic http://superuser.com/questions/96830/network-monitor-tool-closed http://superuser.com/questions/103103/monitor-network-traffic-on-pcs-connected-to-router

Answer (score 0):

[**WireShark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) is great for monitoring all kinds of traffic on a network.

If you'd like to only see local traffic, you can use [**capture filters**](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters).

For example:

```
net 192.168.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some of these applications:

> http://www.freewarehome.com/index.html?http%3A//www.freewarehome.com/Internet/Networking/Network_Monitoring_t.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of detail you are interested choose from this list.

1. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) -- for detailed packet inspection
2. Sysinternals [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) -- for basic connection activity on a Windows machine
3. [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/index.html) for basic connection activity on a unix machine