# How can I find out what programs are accessing the internet?

Tags: windows-xp, internet

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)
>   [Easy-to-use tool to monitor incoming network traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/68115/easy-to-use-tool-to-monitor-incoming-network-traffic)

XP Pro SP3.

How can I find out what programs are accessing the internet?

Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use http://superuser.com/questions/68115/easy-to-use-tool-to-monitor-incoming-network-traffic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Sysinternals TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) application which gives you a nice graphical view of all of the network connections on your system.

Answer (score 5):

Start, run, cmd

```
netstat -b
```

Answer (score 1):

[Nirsoft Currports](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)

I prefer this one to Sysinternals TCPView because it have filters and logs features

[Comodo Firewall](http://personalfirewall.comodo.com/)

In "Custom Policy Mode" you will be prompted for authorization each time a program create a connection...

Update: Look at [this duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use) for screenshots...