# Any good utility to track outgoing traffic and requests from win PC?

Tags: networking, internet, home-networking, proxy, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

Hello, need an advice if there is any good utility to track all outgoing traffic, requests to internet, hosts etc from my home win PC? Just want to keep track of what requests are made from me.

thank you if you could advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NirSoft's **[CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)** is network monitoring software that displays the list of all currently opened TCP/IP and UDP ports on your local computer. For each port in the list, information about the process that opened the port is also displayed, including the process name, full path of the process, version information of the process (product name, file description, and so on), the time that the process was created, and the user that created it.
In addition, CurrPorts allows you to close unwanted TCP connections, kill the process that opened the ports, and save the TCP/UDP ports information to HTML file , XML file, or to tab-delimited text file.

[image]

CurrPorts also automatically mark with pink color suspicious TCP/UDP ports owned by unidentified applications (Applications without version information and icons)

*CurrPorts is freeware and portable (doesn't require to be installed).*

---

As for tracking the the outgoing traffic, you can use the **Remote Address** listed in CurrPorts in **[VisualRoute](http://www.visualroute.com/)**, which will give you a graphical view of Traceroute, Ping, Reverse DNS Connectivity Analysis.

[image]

*VisualRoute is shareware, try before you buy.*

Answer (score 6):

Similar to the above but brought to you by Microsoft, you have the nice lightweight **TCPView** from Mark Russinovich's Sysinternals collection:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

TCPView is a Windows program that will show you detailed listings of all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system, including the local and remote addresses and state of TCP connections. On Windows Server 2008, Vista, and XP, TCPView also reports the name of the process that owns the endpoint. TCPView provides a more informative and conveniently presented subset of the Netstat program that ships with Windows. The TCPView download includes Tcpvcon, a command-line version with the same functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like [Internet Traffic Agent](http://flexbyte.com/internet-traffic-agent/)? There are quite a lot of such tools available - search Google with *outgoing traffic internet windows*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit too powerful for your purpose: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

[image]