# How can I find out what's uploading traffic to the internet?

Tags: windows-7, networking, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any good utility to track outgoing traffic and requests from win PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/99039/any-good-utility-to-track-outgoing-traffic-and-requests-from-win-pc)

Some program I'm running is constantly uploading to the Internet. It's uploaded 300MB in the last few hours. I could reboot and see if it stops, but I'd prefer to find out what it is if possible. I've tried using the resource monitor but it's totally nonsensical - even if I run a broadband speedtest, it barely registers any traffic.

Ideally I'd like to find a tool which can tell me the current bandwidth of each application. I think NetLimiter used to work on XP but it's not supported for Windows 7.

Comment: I found out in the end, it was a video I'd uploaded to facebook, which somehow was still uploading even though I'd cancelled the upload, quit the browser (Firefox) AND ensured it wasn't running in task manager. It must have been using a plugin which uploads out-of-process. Still need the answer to the question though as this is certainly not the first time I've had issues like this!

Answer (score 9):

Two suggestions:

- Use [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to determine the process involved, remote host, etc.
- Use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (formerly [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.org/)) to see the traffic's content (in addition to the remote address, but not the local process).

If your goal is to determine which program is generating a large volume of traffic, it may make sense to use both in combination -- use Wireshark to determine what the traffic is, and what the local and remote ports are; then use TCPView to determine which local program is responsible.

---

As an aside, for folks on Linux: Also consider [Sysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/). The curses interface, [csysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/blob/dev/userspace/sysdig/man/csysdig.md), specifically lets you look at which processes are sending network traffic. After [installing the software](http://www.sysdig.org/install/), the process looks something like this:

- Run `csysdig`
- Select "Views"
- Select the "Connections" view
- Sort by "BPS Out"

The view will provide the command being run for each connection shown.

If you want to view the actual traffic being sent and received, select a connection and press F6 to dig into the syscalls sending and receiving traffic on that connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed earlier versions of ZoneAlarm showed what programs are uploading & downloading. I don't find that anymore probably because i am using a version that's free.

Answer (score 0):

On windows netstat /all in command prompt (start->run->cmd)
it will show everything, but I imagine with uploading that much in such a short space of time, it will have a big number in the 3rd column.
In a *nix, just netstat -a