# How to see what data a windows application send through my network?

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

I want to see what a application send to network and if is possible to edit or stop them. thanks ;)

Comment: duplicate of [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use) and [Any good utility to track outgoing traffic and requests from win PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/99039/any-good-utility-to-track-outgoing-traffic-and-requests-from-win-pc-closed)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what OS you're using and what specific info you need, you might look at [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: I was going to recommend Ethereal but learned that Wireshark is Ethereal. I guess I am behind the times.

Comment: There are rumors that Ethereal/Wireshark team had released another proprietary product; also, just for you to stay tuned, there's a NTop project, which driver (PF_RING) is used in Suricata (and those projects are sharing few developers), NTop, libpcap(forked version, works with wireshark), a libipq-based capture things (Snort supports anything!); it's not only Wireshark for a sniffer market now.

Comment: I already have wireshark and tcpview, but i don't know how to filter only the data passed from that application. there are way to many packets..

Comment: @Totty - It might help if you were able to give some more detail as to what you're looking for and why you want to stop it.

Comment: @Totty - You might also look over at http://ask.wireshark.org/ for help using Wireshark.  You'll find that the OSQA they're running is a lot like SuperUser. ;)

Answer (score 0):

there are several tools available for this some free , some not - as mentioned Wireshark is a great free tool - but most network capture tools are hard to read and understand unless you know whta you are looking at - as for being able to stop or edit whats being sent - thats dependent on the application and its settings -

Answer (score 0):

there are also browser plugins;

and the net had a large list of proxy software that was able to trace passing requests into logs and allow to cease.. actually cant remember the url but there are lots of such little projects, and you can write your own proxy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small program called `Active Ports` for Win32, which lists the ports in use with application name.

http://download.cnet.com/Active-Ports/3000-2651_4-29653.html