# Any tool to monitor which softwares consume the connexion?

Tags: windows-vista, internet, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

I have a wierd problem here.  I'm running Windows Vista, connected to the internet through a 3G key.

Sometimes I go to see how much data is being downloaded and I find 200kb/s even if I'm not using the internet.  I closed all softwares like antivirus and everything and still the internet is being consumed.  Thank god I only pay by the month.

Is there a tool for PC to monitor the programs that are using my connection?

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user  http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually firewall software can do this. I use Sunbelt Personal Firewall on Windows XP, but it doesn't work perfectly on Vista (and definitely doesn't run on 7). I think it is still good for monitoring traffic, though. If it doesn't work, try some of the software here: http://www.thefreecountry.com/security/firewalls.shtml