# Quick easy program to view network traffic?

Tags: windows, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

I leach my neighboors wireless (it's all good I get him back), but I need a way to monitor the incoming and outgoing IPs/domain names on my own end, only because I think I have a trojan.  Like some easy program you know?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested before if you want to view all the network traffic at a low level something like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will let you view the individual packets. It's available for all major operating systems. If you are on windows and just want to view connections on your computer you could try `netstat -a` from the commandline to see what ports are in use.

Answer (score 1):

[SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) from NirSoft is easy to run and lets you see live captures.