# Continuous packet recieve from internet with no visible downloads active.how to monitor my hidden traffic?

Tags: internet, connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

I am connected to the internet and I'm just looking at superuser's page(no browsing or downloading) but in "local area connection status" i see continuous recieve from internet how can i know what is using my trafic in the background?

Comment: Related: [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows, try Nirsoft SmartSniff, or Microsoft Network Monitor.  For instance, you can run SmartSniff in summary mode and sort on packets to find out what's happening.

Refs:
1) http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html
2) http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=983B941D-06CB-4658-B7F6-3088333D062F&displaylang=en