# how can I log all incoming IP traffic from a certain IP address on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, logging, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

I am seeing unusual traffic from one computer on my home network, but I don't know why.

The reason I see it is because my Mcafee firewall is blocking that host because of a UDP port scan.

Is there any way for me to log all incoming traffic only from that host?

I am running Windows XP.

Comment: This question and questions like it have been asked many times. [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](http://superuser.com/questions/22569/) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The tools listed at the link noted by nhinkle are the preferred methods, but you can also enable logging in Windows XP if you don't feel like fooling with 3rd party software.

Start -> Control Panel -> Network Connections.  Right click Local Area Connection (or your particular connection) and choose Properties.  Click Advanced -> Settings -> Advanced.  Under Security Logging, click Settings.

Select the Logging options you prefer and the log path/name and size and click Ok.