# How do I check what processes are actively using the network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

Recently, I discovered that something is downloading on my computer even if I doesn't do anything with it.

Is there any program that can check what process or application that is using the network?

Answer (score 4):

There are many network monitors, I use [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx), you can see how many connections each program has opened and how many bytes are transferred.

Answer (score 3):

Use a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I found one called Net Limiter witch was very simple and powerful. Thanks for your help anyway. :)