# Software that shows network activity?

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

I am looking for a software that monitors, shows and (hopefully) logs network activity like open connections, bytes transferred per connection and the like. Any ideas?

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

> Wireshark is the world's foremost
>   network protocol analyzer. It lets you
>   capture and interactively browse the
>   traffic running on a computer network.
>   It is the de facto (and often de jure)
>   standard across many industries and
>   educational institutions.

Comment: But I guess Wireshark is a lot more than just a network monitor, and also too professional to be used to monitor the network activity, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: By asking for an application that logs the network activity I think the OP can handle the complexity of Wireshark. It's simply the best tool achieving the things he wants, even if the learning curve is not as flat as with some other tool.

Comment: Wireshark is anything but easy to setup and read for the average user. Yes it is extremely powerful, but it is not ideal unless you have a solid understanding of a lot of networking principles.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://www.wireshark.org/&ei=SC3KTcvRM4nCvQOUzuX7Cg&usg=AFQjCNHE63N0oC3FKruR4eA0xdxI87juZg) is the way to go.

It is powerful and more importantly, it is free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is definitely the poweruser way to go, but if you want something "dumbed down" you can always try analogx netstat live.

It won't show as much detail but you can see your current usage among your installed network adaptors.

Comment: I thought that Wireshark's primary purpose was to capture and analyse the data going out on the network (and that's how I have used it earlier). What I'm interested is mainly the statistics, instead of the actual data.