# Free network monitor show download/upload speed on system tray

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

I'm looking for a free software show download/upload speed on system tray. I found DU Meter, but it's not free. Anybody know ?

Comment: Your OS is... (peers into crystal ball)

Comment: My OS is windows 7

Comment: There is a decent built-in network monitor in Windows 7 (probably Vista, too) - although it doesn't show up in the tray. Just `Ctrrl-Shift-Esc` to bring up `Windows Task Manager` and go to the 'Networking' tab.  OR. Under the 'Performance' tab, click 'Resource monitor'. That brings a comprehensive aggregated view of different performance metrics of the system, including network speeds.

Answer (score 5):

[NetSpeedMonitor](http://www.floriangilles.com/software/netspeedmonitor/) shows download/upload speed on system tray. It's free and lightweight.

> NetSpeedMonitor is a lightweight Network Monitoring Toolbar for your
>   Windows Taskbar designed to be used on computers that run Windows XP,
>   Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista or Windows 7. With NetSpeedMonitor
>   you can monitor the current speed (up- and downstream) of your Network
>   Interfaces and the amount of data transferred.

[image]

Comment: I've started using this app today, and I must tell that it's become indispensable for me from now on. It's very light, and the configuration options are versatile.

Comment: Nice App but it often crashes and takes explorer.exe down with it

Comment: Never experienced that kind of problems.

Comment: This link doesn't show the utility anymore but I found it in [Softpedia (both x86 and x64 available)](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Bandwidth-Tools/NetSpeedMonitor.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

I currently use [Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/).  It's stable and non-intrusive and can show traffic in several different ways, including a variably-transparent popup window, a taskbar graph and an animated system tray icon.  I've also used [NetMeter](http://www.metal-machine.de/readerror/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=cat1).

Comment: You only can download a 30-days trial version of Networx.

Comment: Yeah, that changed recently. Older versions still work fine: I'm using version 5.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but, I know people who have had good results with [Free Meter](http://miechu.pl/freemeter/download.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[NetTraffic](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/nettraffic.html) seems to do what you want.