# How can I track HTTP headers sent and received from my computer?

Tags: networking, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

I know there is a program called [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for Firefox. Then there is [ieHTTPheaders](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders.html) for Internet Explorer.

I knew another good program – someone told me, but I forgot. That program could display traffic for *all* programs, not just IE and Firefox.

What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for Windows and Linux. Remember to install [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/).

[Tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) for Linux console.