# What can I use to track application internet usage?

Tags: windows-8, internet, sniffing, windows-store-app

I want to see what connections my Modern UI apps are making, and more specifically, where they are sending information, what the protocol looks like, headers, etc. Is there a program that can help me do this?

Comment: [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use/22572#22572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will show you all the packets that are coming in and out of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is probably the most complete solution.  If you're just looking for connections, [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) works well.