# Progam to tell what programs are accessing the internet

Tags: windows-7, windows

I connect to the internet using my cellphone's internet, and something on my PC secretely ate up 300MB of my data. I use Windows 7 Home Premium, and have Norton Antivirus Installed. I've turned off Windows Updates. What could have done this? Is there a program that can tell what programs are accessing the internet from my PC?

**Edit**
I connected again and it took away some more data.

Comment: @Ramhound Ashton was an autocowreck. I'm typing on my tab and it auto corrected a misspelled 'What' to Ashton :-)

Comment: Open a command prompt as administrator, type `netstat -b -n` and press Enter. This command will display all active connections. For real-time monitoring, run `resmon`and check the Network tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open an elevated command prompt and execute `netstat -a -b`. This will list all executables currently connected or listening on a port. It is not uncommon to find over a hundred entries, even when you're not actively using your internet connection. Most of these are not consuming large amounts of data. Measured over several hours, 300 MB of unidentified traffic is not normally worrisome, but sufficient to expect the culprit is easily found.

You can monitor how much bandwidth a process uses from Windows itself on the Network tab in the Resource Monitor, opened with `resmon` or via the Performance tab in Windows Task Manager. The first list, 'Processes with Network activity', shows time-averaged numbers of bytes used per second for individual processes. I am unaware of a built-in feature to monitor these figures over longer periods. If the process does not immediately reveal itself, you would have to keep an eye on it.